Running JupyterLab in AzureML Studio with a custom environment?
We have successfully created a custom environment "pangeo" in Azure ML Studio by clicking the "environments" tab and using the GUI to create a custom conda environment:

There used to be an option in the compute instance creation GUI to select an environment, but this went away a few weeks ago (at least on our Azure ML Studio instance).
My question is: How can we use this custom environment to run notebooks in Jupyerlab on an Azure ML compute instance?
(Note: I do know how to log into the compute instance and create a custom kernel using this approach, but I'd like to just use the environment I already created for each compute instance I start)

check if my solution working or not. @Rich Signell

You don't have option to select environment directly but you can give the custom script as creation and startup script.
Creation script will run once while creating instance and startup script runs whenever the instance is started.
While creating the compute instance in
Applications tab you will find the option like below.

Below is the sample script for setting up custom conda environment.
#!/bin/bash
 
set -e

# This script creates a custom conda environment and kernel based on a sample yml file.

source /anaconda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
conda env create -f env.yml
echo "Activating new conda environment"
conda activate envname
conda install -y ipykernel
sudo -u azureuser -i <<'EOF'
echo "Installing kernel"
source /anaconda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
conda activate envname
python -m ipykernel install --user --name envname --display-name "mykernel"
echo "Conda environment setup successfully."
EOF

Some examples what you can do.

Install packages, tools, and software
Mount data
Create custom conda environment and Jupyter kernels
Clone git repositories and set git config
Set network proxies
Set environment variables
Install JupyterLab extensions

You can also check these sample scripts.

Thanks for this, but we were hoping to reuse an existing conda envrionment instead of building it every time we create a new compute instance, because our environment takes about 20 minutes to build!   Is it possible to use an existing environment with this script-based approach?

No option for adding existing environment. But if you add conda environment script in creation script option it runs only one time.

Okay, it's just strange because a month ago we could just select a custom environment in the Azure ML Studio web interface when we created a new compute instance.   But that capability seems to be gone now.    I guess we WILL have to use the script approach.

Yes, need to use the script.
